# Compare items within an array without loosing information

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array of product information. I have a loop that runs through the array and compares the prices to find the lowest one.

```
$rows = get_field('variations',$product_id);
   if($rows){
      $prices = array();
      foreach($rows as $row){
         $prices[] = $row['variation_price'];
      }
   //Getting the lowest price from the array
   $lowest_price = min($prices);
   }
   echo $lowest_price;
```

However I now need to get the other information that is associated with the "lowest price" array set. IE. I need the ID of the lowest price product etc.

Any help is welcome!

Here is a dump of the array

```
Array
```

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [] => 
            [variation_title] => Small Business
            [checkout] => cart
            [trial] => Array
                (
                    [0] => trial
                )

```
        [variation_price] => 7
        [variation_subscription_cycle] => /month
        [variation_id] => 405
        [variation_url] => 
        [custom] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [custom_field] => 1 Domain
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [custom_field] => 1 Million QPM
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [custom_field] => 50 Records
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [custom_field] => DNS Alias
                    )

            )

        [css_styles] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [] => 
        [variation_title] => Medium Business
        [checkout] => cart
        [trial] => Array
            (
                [0] => trial
            )

        [variation_price] => 35
        [variation_subscription_cycle] => /month
        [variation_id] => 286
        [variation_url] => 
        [custom] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [custom_field] => 10 Domains
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [custom_field] => 5 Million QPM
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [custom_field] => 500 Records
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [custom_field] => DNS Alias
                    )

            )

        [css_styles] => ribbon
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [] => 
        [variation_title] => Large Business
        [checkout] => cart
        [trial] => Array
            (
                [0] => trial
            )

        [variation_price] => 100
        [variation_subscription_cycle] => /month
        [variation_id] => 406
        [variation_url] => 
        [custom] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [custom_field] => 50 Domains
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [custom_field] => 15 Million QPM
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [custom_field] => 1,,500 Records
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [custom_field] => DNS Alias
                    )

            )

        [css_styles] => 
    )
```

)

Comment: Update your question with the contents of `var_dump($rows);`

Comment: Figured it out by doing from the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Test {

public $a;
public $b;

    public function __construct($a1,$b1)
{
    $this->a = $a1;
    $this->b = $b1;
}
}

$first = new test(1,12);
$second = new test(4,25);
$third = new test(7,9);

$values = [$first, $second, $third];

function compare (Test $firstObject, Test $secondObject) {

return $firstObject->a > $secondObject->a;

}

usort($values, "compare");

    var_dump($values);

?>
```